# Real world applications of triple point?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, phase-transition, kinetic-theory

What are the real world applications of triple of water? And is it worth researching what factors could effect it?

Comment: You are assuming there is only one - why?

Comment: Maybe it sounds like I am assuming there is one, but are there any?

Answer (score 2):

It is a way to establish an accurate temperature. In the past, it was used as the definition of 0.01 C.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one: A special condition of the triple point- its particular value at *atmospheric pressure*- is the thermodynamic limit of superheat, which is of vital importance in the design and operation of thermal inkjet printheads.